# Connect 4 Java, checking win conditions?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public boolean isGameOver() {
    if (getWinner() == null)
        return false;
    for (int i=0; i<BOARD_WIDTH; i++){
        if (board[0][i]!=null){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public Player getWinner() {
    Player winner = getToMove();
    if (checkRows() || checkCols() || checkLowDiag() || checkHighDiag() ){
        return winner;
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean checkRows(){
    for (int i=0;i<BOARD_HEIGHT; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<BOARD_WIDTH; j++){
            if (getSquare(i, j) != null && getSquare(i, j) == getToMove()){
                if (getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i, j+1) && getSquare(i, j+1) != null &&
                        getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i, j+2) && getSquare(i, j+2) != null &&
                        getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i, j+3) && getSquare(i, j+3) != null)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkCols(){
    for (int i=0;i<BOARD_HEIGHT; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<BOARD_WIDTH; j++){
            if (getSquare(i, j) != null && getSquare(i, j) == getToMove()){
                if (getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i+1, j) && getSquare(i+1, j) != null &&
                        getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i+2, j) && getSquare(i+2, j) != null &&
                        getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i+3, j) && getSquare(i+3, j) != null)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkLowDiag(){
    for (int i=0; i<BOARD_HEIGHT; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<BOARD_WIDTH; j++){
            if (getSquare(i, j) != null && getSquare(i, j) == getToMove()){
                if (getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i+1, j+1) && getSquare(i+1, j+1) != null &&
                        getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i+2, j+2) && getSquare(i+2, j+2) != null &&
                        getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i+3, j+3) && getSquare(i+3, j+3) != null)
                    return true;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}

public boolean checkHighDiag(){
    for (int i=0; i<BOARD_HEIGHT; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<BOARD_WIDTH; j++){
            if (getSquare(i, j) != null && getSquare(i, j) == getToMove()){
                if (getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i-1, j+1) && getSquare(i-1, j+1) != null &&
                        getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i-2, j+2) && getSquare(i-2, j+2) != null &&
                        getSquare(i, j) == getSquare(i-3, j+3) && getSquare(i-3, j+3) != null)
                    return true;
            }
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

For some reason, my game over function is not working correctly. I'm not sure why. It returns true while the game is still going on, and false when the game is over. This is for a connect four game, by the way. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: getToMove gives the player that is about to move. It just gives the variable Player toMove, where toMove is decided as 'x' first. In the makeMove function, I change toMove to the next player. Here are the relevant methods.

```
    public boolean makeMove(int col) {
    if (board[0][col] != null){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        for (int i=BOARD_HEIGHT-1; i>=0; i--){
            if (board[i][col] == null){
                board[i][col] = getToMove();
                saveRow.add(i);
                saveCol.add(col);
                if (getToMove() == x)
                    toMove = o;
                else if (getToMove() == o)
                    toMove = x;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

    public Player getSquare(int row, int col) {
    if (row > BOARD_HEIGHT-1 || row < 0 || col > BOARD_WIDTH-1 || col < 0)
        return null;
    else return board[row][col];
}


    public Player getToMove() {
    return toMove;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for "getToMove()" function?

Comment: First thing I noticed is that you always go to far with your check-functions e.g. 4 in a row can only start only between first and 4th-last column. I guess you would get IndexOutOfBounds if you would use board[][] instead of getSquare.

Comment: What do you mean by go too far with my check functions? Should I subtract some numbers from my BOARD_HEIGHT/BOARD_WIDTH in the for-loops?

Comment: In isGameOver function, inside first for loop, it returns true, if at least one of first column cell is not null, is that the expected behaviour? May be what you need is to check at least one first column cell is null and return false ( I don't actually know this game, so I may be wrong). And in checkColls, checkRows, ... functions, I think null check done in inside if condition is redundant, because you have already check whether (i,j) is not null and then in the inside loop you have check other three cells equal to null.

Comment: Yeah, I just assume that if all columns are full (because (0, 0) is the upper left), then the game is over. The null check is redundant though, and I removed  that. Thank you. Still having trouble with the function though.

Answer (score 0):

First if condition should check whether winner is not null, and then return true. Because if there is already a winner, game is over then. But if there is no winner, then you should check whether players has filled all the columns by checking whether all the cells in the top row is filled. If at least one cell is not filled, game is not over, so return false. otherwise return true.

```
if (winner != null) game is over
else {
   if (one of top row cell is null) game is not over
   else game is over.
}
```

In your current logic, you have check whether there is no winner, if there is no winner you return false without checking whether game board is already filled. You check whether gameboard is already filled only if there is a winner. so that logic is incorrect. Correct logic is what I have mentioned above.